# How to replace links

Tags: jquery, replace

I have 4 links

```
<a href="/search/Assassins%20Creed/" class="eTag">Assassins Creed</a> 
<a href="/search/Dead%20Rising%202/" class="eTag">Dead Rising 2</a> 
<a href="/search/Battlefield/" class="eTag">Battlefield</a> 
<a href="/search/Rising/" class="eTag">Rising</a>
```

I need replace "/search/" to "/searchq?="

If i use this script:

```
$('.eTag').attr('href',$('.eTag').attr('href').replace('/search/','/searchq?='));
```

Links are:

```
<a href="/searchq?=Assassins%20Creed/" class="eTag">Assassins Creed</a> 
<a href="/searchq?=Assassins%20Creed/" class="eTag">Dead Rising 2</a> 
<a href="/searchq?=Assassins%20Creed/" class="eTag">Battlefield</a> 
<a href="/searchq?=Assassins%20Creed/" class="eTag">Rising</a>
```

Why and how do I replace "/search/" to "/searchq?=" ?

Comment: you just did it. What's the problem?

Comment: @PabloFernandez Take a closer look at the last code. They are all the same URLs. All that needs to be replaced is the `/search/` to `/search?q=`, but not the actual search query in it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to loop over all of them:

```
$('.eTag').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('/search/','/searchq?='));
});
```

I'm amazed that your code even ran.

Comment: There's nothing to be amazed. In jQuery, when you invoke a "setter-like" method on a collection (such as `attr` in this case) it will perform in __on every element of that collection__. When you invoke a "getter-like" (again `attr` but with a single argument) it will __pick the first__. That's why every item says Assasins Creed (great game BTW)

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to pass a function to `.attr()`.

```
$('.eTag').attr('href',function(i,href) {
    return href.replace('/search/','/searchq?='); 
});
```

The reason why was that this:

```
$('.eTag').attr('href')
```

...only gives you the result from the first element found.

Comment: Huh, haven't seen that syntax before. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

what you have done is almost correct but it will point to same link because the attr value will be returned from 1st element always. do it like

```
$('.eTag').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('/search/','/searchq?='));
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/USzfa/

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion, you can also do it in plain javascript, without jQuery:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('eTag'),
    l = tags.length,
    i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  tags[i].innerText = tags[i].innerText.replace('/search/', '/searchq?=');
}
```

This might be a bit noisier, but it's 33% faster as you can see in [this jsperf test run](http://jsperf.com/replace-etags). (Note there's also a 3rd solution, using a wrapper `<div>` that is about an order of magnitude faster, but not sure if you can do that)